# Make dome into threes

Tags: vertices

[image]

Trying to make the Talisman from "9"

I need to know how to split the dome into threes

Thanks

Comment: Create the dome with 10 verts sphere and rest array.

Comment: Does it really need to be linked to the dome? If I see that https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/nine/images/a/aa/Thesource.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/395?cb=20120105021841 I think should be separated pieces.

Comment: So, how do you do it?